# Does this algorithm complexity is good?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I have an algorithm of complexity O(|e1|*|e2|) where |e1| and |e2| is the number of edges in graph G1 and G2. So does this complexity is good? In another words, what does this complexity means? Sorry but im nubby in complexity

Comment: It depends on what problem the algorithm solves.

Comment: Suppose for random walk with restart

Comment: That doesn't tell me what problem the algorithm solves.  It might be an *efficient* algorithm, but we'd need to compare it to other possible algorithms for the same problem.

Comment: @hardmath the paper told for computing the steady state for page rank algorithm for a graph where its nodes consists of combination nodes from g1 and g2

Comment: Giving a citation for that paper (if published) would improve your Question.

Comment: @hardmath reweitghed random walks for graph matching(page 499) after algo 1

Comment: Is it this: [Reweighted Random Walks for Graph Matching](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-15555-0_36) by Minsu Cho, Jungmin Lee, and Kyoung Mu Lee (ECCV 2010) ?

Comment: @hardmath yes this is the paper

Comment: Please edit the title and body of your Question.  In broad terms "complexity $O(e_1 e_2)$" for an algorithm means that many steps are required by it.  Whether this is "good" needs more careful definitions.  You should describe the problem that the algorithm solves in order to make the Question accessible to more Readers, and include the citation details for the published algorithm you want to ask about.  Comments are considered "ephemeral" on Math.SE, so these details should appear in the body of your Question.  If English is not a strong language for you, I can help make the post grammatical.